# Is there a way to make collision between shapes in PyGame using colors?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Is there a way to make a collision in pygame when a shape touches a specific color. Like when a shape controlled somehow(example: a bouncy ball, a moving shape, etc.) can there be a way to detect that it has touched a specific type of color?

Comment: Without knowing your reasoning, it's hard to make a suggestion.  If the objects had static colours (e.g.: were *always* green), you could just split them into separate lists and collide-test only those colours you were interested in.  For dynamic colours, I would just use regular geometric collision, then check the current colour to see if that that still counts as a "hit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, here an example from sentdex
link : https://pythonprogramming.net/detecting-collisions-intermediate-python-tutorial/

```
def is_touching(b1,b2):
    return np.linalg.norm(np.array([b1.x,b1.y])-np.array([b2.x,b2.y]))< (b1.size + b2.size)


def handle_collisions(blob_list):
    blues, reds, greens = blob_list
    for blue_id, blue_blob in blues.copy().items():
        for other_blobs in blues, reds, greens:
            for other_blob_id, other_blob in other_blobs.copy().items():
                if blue_blob == other_blob:
                    pass
                else:
                    if is_touching(blue_blob, other_blob):
                        blue_blob + other_blob
                        if other_blob.size <= 0:
                            del other_blobs[other_blob_id]
                        if blue_blob.size <= 0:
                            del blues[blue_id]
                            
    return blues, reds, greens
```